# Golf Me A Bubble Sort

Tags: code-golf, sorting, algorithm

Your task is to create a program that performs a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) on a given array until it is sorted.

---

### Algorithm

In order to qualify as a bubble sort, the program must operate as follows:

- Each pass goes through the array, looks at every two adjacent elements in turn, and potentially swaps them.
- Each pass goes through the array in the same direction and without gaps. There are no partial passes - each pass must go through the whole array.
- The program must never compare or swap array elements that aren't adjacent.
- A sufficient (and finite) number of passes must be performed, such that the output array is guaranteed to be sorted. (E.g. you can safely stop if there was a whole pass without any swaps, or after `len(array)` passes have been made, etc.)

---

### Rules

1. You must provide a sufficient explanation for how your answer does a bubble sort.
2. You may *not* use built-in or standard library sorting algorithms. You must make your own code.
3. Your program should take an array of numbers as input and output them in the correct order.

   - Input: `10 5 9 2 . . . (and so on)`
   - The program should *always* output the sorted array.
   - Output can be an array returned by the program when run, or it can modify the input array in-place.
   - Output can also be the correctly ordered values separated by whitespace.
4. Speed does not matter as much as if the program functions.

---

### Test Cases

- `10 5 9 2 1 6 8 3 7 4` (you can format it differently depending on your language)
- `1 2 5 4 3`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: @Suever There is no set number of comparisons for this challenge.

Comment: Saying "use this algorithm" is usually seen as a [non-observable requirement](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11197/60919). Perhaps "perform _one iteration_" of bubble sort is a better challenge?

Comment: Also, 10 minutes in the sandbox isn't very long. You should leave it there for longer (at least a day, if not more) to get more feedback first.

Comment: @FlipTack I will remember for next time I ask something

Comment: It seems very similar to [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92753/60919), except that one has a parameter for max comparisons.

Comment: It's well known that many people mix up the various simple quadratic sorts. I agree with FlipTack that asking specifically for bubble sort makes a bad question, but I would add that if you *do* want to require a specific algorithm then you must clearly specific exactly what qualifies as that algorithm. This question as it stands is inviting arguments over the difference between insertion sort, selection sort, and bubble sort.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: It could be distinguished from those two, by requiring that comparisons are only ever allowed between two adjacent elements.

Comment: @smls, that doesn't distinguish insertion sort from bubble sort, which rather supports my point.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92753/bubble-sorting-in-progress

Comment: @carusocomputing This challenge requires you to perform a bubble sort until the array is sorted, rather than a specific number of times.

Comment: And we're saying that's not a good requirement, because [code-golf] generally only cares about input and output, not process.

Comment: @mbomb007 There are differences. My challenge asks that it takes 1 input and outputs an array that is _in order_ no matter what, while the other challenge takes 2 inputs and only outputs the array if it is sorted in n iterations of bubble sort, where n is the second argument.

Comment: Maybe you should read the meta post that Fliptack linked to.

Comment: ckjbgames, I edited the task to add a clear(er) specification of what counts as a bubble sort is. Feel free to revert if you don't agree. @PeterTaylor, does this sufficiently distinguish it from insertion sort?

Comment: @smls I think this distinguishes it enough.

Comment: Bubble sort is well defined and the OP has a link to the wikipedia article for it. In my opinion this should be more than sufficient when it comes to distinguishing bubble sort from other sorts.

Comment: @FlipTack in his defense, it has been upvoted 3 times.

Comment: @JackBates yes, but also two downvotes, and the post was actually closed at first until it was more clearly specified. These flaws could have been eliminated by posting in the sandbox first, as everyone should.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```
f(a:b:c)=min a b:f(max a b:c)
f x=x
foldr(\_->f)=<<id
```

Usage example: `foldr(\_->f)=<<id $ [3,1,6,4,3,8,3,1,1,2]` -> `[1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,6,8]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkWiVZJWsaZubmaeQqJBklaaRm1gBZiVrcqUpVNhWcKXbpuXnpBRpxMTr2qVp2trYZKb8z00EqrdVKCjKzCtRUFFIV4g21jHUMdMx0THWsdABsQ11jGL/AwA).

How it works: `f` does one iteration by keeping the minimum of the first two elements and appending a recursive call with the maximum of the first two elements and all the other elements. It stops when there are less than two  elements in the list. The main function calls `f` `length <input>` times by iterating over the input list via `fold` but ignoring the elements.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>77</s> 75 bytes

```
i=1;while any(diff(x)<0),i=mod(i,rows(x)-1)+1;x(i:i+1)=sort(x(i:i+1));end,x
```

A crude first attempt. I'm sure I'll be able to golf this a bit. Takes input as a row vector.

**Explanation:**

```
i=1;                           % Initialize iterator to 1;
    while                      % Start loop
              diff(x)     % diff(x) creates a vector with the difference between
                          % adjacent elements

              diff(x)<0   % Checks if there are less than 0 (unsorted vector)

          any(diff(x)<0)  % True if there's at least one negative difference

i=mod(i,rows(x)-1)+1      % i++, but loop around if it's equal to the number of rows          
x(i:i+1)=sort(x(i:i+1);   % Take two adjacent elements, sort them and put them back in
end,x                     % End loop and display result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 44 bytes

```perl6
{.[*]=.[1,0]if [<] $_ for |(.[1..*]Z$_)xx$_}
```

Takes an array of numbers, and modifies it in-place (so that it is sorted after calling the lambda).

#### How it works

```perl6
{                                          }  # A lambda taking one argument.
                                              # e.g [a,b,c]
                            .[1..*]Z$_        # Zip it with itself offset by one.
                                              # e.g. (b,a),(c,b),(d,c)
                          |(          )xx$_   # Repeat this by the input's length.
                                              # e.g. (b,a),(c,b),(d,c),(b,a),(c,b),(d,c),(b,a),(c,b),(d,c)
                      for                     # For each of those pairs:
            if [<] $_                         # If its 1st element is less than the 2nd:
 .[*]=.[1,0]                                  # Swap their values.
```

This works because the elements of a Perl 6 array are actually mutable item containers (akin to pointers in C except that they hide themselves well). So in the list we iterate over, each pair consists of two item containers from the array.

Comment: It is fine to use this.

Answer (score 1):

### SmileBASIC, 79 bytes

```
DEF S A
FOR Z=0TO I
FOR I=1TO LEN(A)-1SWAP A[I-(A[I-1]>A[I])],A[I]NEXT
NEXT
END
```

This one is pretty simple. It just runs `LEN(A)` (actually LEN(A)+2 just in case) iterations of bubble sort, which is guaranteed to sort the array.

The only slightly interesting part is how I avoided using IF/THEN:
`SWAP A[I-(A[I-1]>A[I])],A[I]`. If the two adjacent values are in the wrong positions (if `(A[I-1]>A[I])` is true), it swaps `A[I-1]` with `A[I]`, otherwise it swaps `A[I-0]` with `A[I]`, which does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript <del>98</del>, <del>97</del>, 91 Bytes**

edit: removed unneeded semicolon and fixed broken code. Also moved some variable declarations and increments around.

```
x=>{for(h=1;h--;){for(i=d=0;d<x.length;i=d++){if(x[i]>x[d]){y=x[i];x[i]=x[d];x[d]=y;h=1}}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
x=>{
    for(h=1;h--;){
        for(i=d=0;d<x.length;i=d++){
            if(x[i]>x[d]){
                y=x[i];
                x[i]=x[d];
                x[d]=y;
                h=1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

```
x=>{
    for(h=1;h--;){  //set the change tracker, h, to true. On the start of each loop, evaluate it, then decrement it. 
                    //If true, sets to false. If false, exits the loop and sets it to -1.

        for(i=d=0;d<x.length;i=d++){ //i and d are our array indexers. They're both set to null for the first loop, then on subsequent loops i is set to d, then d is incremented.
                                     // Therefore, on each subsequent loop, d will be 1 more than i.



            if(x[i]>x[d]){ //if the previous value, i, is greater than the current value, d, switch their places using the temporary variable y.
                y=x[i];
                x[i]=x[d];
                x[d]=y;
                h=1     //set the change tracker to true.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's rather simple and embarrassingly long, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Explanation please? That is in the requirements.

Comment: Sorry about that! I've edited it into the bottom of my original post.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 104 bytes

Straightforward implementation.

```python
L=input()
while L!=sorted(L):
 for i in range(len(L)-1):
    if L[i]>L[i+1]:L[i],L[i+1]=L[i+1],L[i]
print L
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@@9jm5lXUFqioclVnpGZk6rgo2hbnF9Ukpqi4aNpxaWQll@kkKmQmadQlJiXnqqRk5oHFNc1BEpxZqYp@ERnxtoBCW3DWCsQWwfCtoVQIF4sV0FRZl6Jgs///9GmOiY6xjpGOoaxAA)

While not sorted, for each index in the list, swap with next item if greater.